# Replacing all values in a Pandas column, with no conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe with a column full of values I want to replace with another, non conditionally.

For the purpose of this question, let's assume I don't know how long this column is and I don't want to iterate over its values.

Using `.replace()` is not appropriate since I don't know which values are in that column: I want to replace all values, non conditionally.

Using `df.loc[<row selection>, <column selection>]` is not appropriate since there is no row selection logic: I want all the rows and simply writing True (as in `data.loc[True, 'ColumnName'] = new_value`) returns `KeyError(True,)`.  I tried `data.loc[1, 'ColumnName'] = new_value` and it works but it really looks like a shitty solution.

If I know `len()` of `data['ColumnName']` I could create an array of that size, filled with as many time of my `new_value` and simply replace the column with that array. 10 lines of code to do something simpler than something that requires 1 line of code (doing so conditionally): this is also not ok.

How can I tell Pandas in 1 line: all the values in `ColumnName` are now `new_value`? I refuse to believe there's no way to tell Pandas not to bother me with conditions.

Comment: `data['ColumnName'] = new_value`?

Comment: Nope. df['ColumnName'] = new_values. Plural. That requires an array of the correct size. I only have the value, not the array. I could create the array new_values = [new value, new value, new value,] but... that would be a crappy solution.

Comment: If there is only one value, why do you even need to create an array? Assigning `new_value` to a Series automatically ensures that EVERY element of the Series object is updated with the new value.

Comment: Assigning new_value gives SyntaxError. https://i.imgur.com/QUJpBmx.png

Comment: What kind of environment are you working in?  That's a weird-looking syntax error, and @VishnuKunchur's answer is exactly the way to do it.

Comment: I'm using the immediate window in Visual Studio while debugging. Could be its fault: let me check if I put it in-code.

Comment: aaaaaand it was the environment, he was correct. I really don't get why it refuses to run perfectly fine code sometimes! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Use Jupyter Notebook to test and document your code, before putting all these pieces together into production.

Comment: Yeah, I thought the immediate window was as good as a notebook but apparently it is not. Perfectly fine code gives errors, so I assumed it was Pandas refusing to run it. Will stick to the notebook now, thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As I explained in the comment, you don't need to create an array.
Let's say you have `df`:

```
  InvoiceNO Month  Year Size
0         1     1     2    7
1         2     1     2    8
2         3     2     2   11
3         4     3     2    9
4         5     7     2  8.5
```

..and you want to change all values in `InvoiceNO` to `1234`:

```
df['InvoiceNO'] = 1234
```

Output:

```
   InvoiceNO Month  Year Size
0       1234     1     2    7
1       1234     1     2    8
2       1234     2     2   11
3       1234     3     2    9
4       1234     7     2  8.5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
   {'num1'        : [3, 5, 9, 9, 14, 1],
    'num2'        : [3, 5, 9, 9, 14, 1]},
     index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
print(df)
print('\n')
df['num1'] = 100
print(df)
df['num1'] = 'Hi'
print('\n')
print(df)
```

The output is

```
  num1  num2
0     3     3
1     5     5
2     9     9
3     9     9
4    14    14
5     1     1


   num1  num2
0   100     3
1   100     5
2   100     9
3   100     9
4   100    14
5   100     1


  num1  num2
0   Hi     3
1   Hi     5
2   Hi     9
3   Hi     9
4   Hi    14
5   Hi     1
```